# Why can’t I use a Live Photo as a wallpaper

Tags: iphone

I've got an iPhone 6. I know it is capable to set a live photo as the device wallpaper. But I couldn't do it because it only gives me 'still' and 'perspective' as the options. So how can I set a live photo as a wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 6 does not support live wallpapers. You need to use a jailbreak tweak like [LiveWallEnabler](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3pkj1u/release_livewallenabler_enable_live_wallpapers_on/) to enable live wallpapers using long press on a device without 3D Touch hardware.